undetected chromedriver's error: OSError: [WinError 6] Handle is invalid
I'm currently producing a program that automatically logs in by accessing a specific site using Python. When I used selenium only on the site itself during production, I saw the console because the Chrome closed automatically, but there was no error, so I thought that the site closed the Chrome, so I used the undetected_chromedriver. An error occurred in the process and I'm posting something
This is my code:
import time
import pyperclip
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class LoginService():

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None

    def open_web_mode(self):
        self.driver = uc.Chrome()
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

    def close_browser(self):
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()
            self.driver = None

    def login(self):
        browser = self.driver.get("https://www.kftcvan.or.kr/member/login/form.do#")
        time.sleep(2) 
        Alert(self.driver).dismiss()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Login = LoginService()
    Login.open_web_mode()
    Login.login()
    time.sleep(5)
    Login.close_browser()

This is an error code:
Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x0000016EF99FD6C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wonky\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 846, in __del__
    self.quit()
  File "C:\Users\wonky\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 801, in quit
    time.sleep(0.1)
OSError: [WinError 6] Handle is invalid


I would check again after removing the Alert(self.driver)... line.

Chrome stops running even though you modified self.driver = uc.Chrome to webdriver.Chrome (service=ChromeService().install()) and removed Alert(self.driver).dismiss()
